# PHP Get line matching phrase TXT File

Tags: php, file, search

So i've got a bunch of data in my .txt in this format

```
order_number
first_name
last_name
email_address
```

And i'm trying to figure out how to make it so if i search for example `john_doe` (has to be `john_doe` exact no `john_do`)
it grabs `john_doe` from the `.txt` and displays `order_number` `first_name`(`john_doe` in this case) `last_name` `email_address`.

I have no clue how to, i looked in `preg_match` but that didn't work out good. If anyone could help me with it that would be appreciated.

Example as requested:

```
"28DP9", "JOHAN", "VAN DIJK", "removed@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Could you supply a sample of this data (3/4 people). (***Also***, *you'll most likely have to redevelop how you're storing this data as this isn't manageable.*)

Comment: @Darren Updated with a example of how i'm storing it in the .txt.

Comment: How did it not work out?

Comment: It's fixed, i accepted the answer that Darren wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be storing it as "*Comma-Separated Values*" (`CSV`). You'll need to fetch this data, sort it and search it. Take the following data for example:

```
"28DP9", "JOHAN", "VAN DIJK", "removed@gmail.com"
"28DP9", "JOHAN", "VAN DIJK", "removed@gmail.com"
"28DP9", "JOHAN", "VAN DIJK", "removed@gmail.com"
"28DP9", "john_doe", "VAN DIJK", "IAM_john_doe@gmail.com"
"28DP9", "JOHAN", "VAN DIJK", "removed@gmail.com"
"28DP9", "JOHAN", "VAN DIJK", "removed@gmail.com"
```

Now there is our one row we want to find (*`john_doe`*), what we need though is to sort the data first into an associative array. That's done simply via a combination of [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)/[`foreach()`](http://php.net/foreach):

```
$new = array();
$data_array = explode("\n", $data);
foreach($data_array as $element) {
    list($order_number, $first, $last, $email) = explode(",", str_replace('"', '',$element));
    $new[] = array(
        'order_number' => $order_number,
        'first_name' => $first,
        'last_name' => $last,
        'email' => $email,
    );
}
```

<sup>*Reference: `$data` is the data from your file (most likely fetched from [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)). We also remove all `"` from the data as we don't require it. That's done via [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)*</sup>

---

Now that we've sorted it, we need to search it. This is done with a combination of `array_map()`/`array_filter()`:

```
$search_word = 'john_doe';

$found = array_filter(array_map(function($element) use ($search_word){
    if(trim($element['first_name']) == $search_word) {
        return $element; 
    }
}, $new));
```

The above search runs through each element (*basically a glorified `foreach()` loop.*) and only returns the element that has the search word you require. Thus, the search returns the following from the example:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [order_number] => 28DP9
            [first_name] =>  john_doe
            [last_name] =>  VAN DIJK
            [email] =>  IAM_john_doe@gmail.com
        )

)
```

[**Example/Demo**](https://eval.in/584408)